# Tracking the content

Tags: content, tracking

How to track a particular event at regular time intervals?

For instance tracking the Linkedin companies, jobs related to specific technology (cloud computing, big data, etc.). How can we do that?

Comment: Do you mean fetching the content of specific website at regular time in order to retrieve something useful?

Answer (score 1):

I read the question as Larry did.

If available, fetch a [RSS feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) (or use a service's [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api)) with e.g. [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php) via a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). I use this technique to (among other things) fetch the number of likes from Facebook.